# I am trying to create multiple popup with read more buttom

Tags: jquery, css, popup

problem is here, when i am using this code in my loop with multiple post , popup open only one read more button ,it's does not working with all read more button

```
<style>
            #overlay {
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                background: #999;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                opacity: 0.8;
                z-index: 100;
            }
            #popup {
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                background: #fff;
                width: 500px;
                height: 500px;
                margin-left: -250px; /*Half the value of width to center div*/
                margin-top: -250px; /*Half the value of height to center div*/
                z-index: 200;
            }
            #popupclose {
                float: right;
                padding: 10px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .popupcontent {
                padding: 10px;
            }
            #button {
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="maincontent">
        <h1>Page Content<h2>
        <button id="button">Show Popup</button>
    </div>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div id="popup">
        <div class="popupcontrols">
            <span id="popupclose">X</span>
        </div>
        <div class="popupcontent">
            <h1>Some Popup Content</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Initialize Variables
        var closePopup = document.getElementById("popupclose");
        var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
        var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
        var button = document.getElementById("button");
        // Close Popup Event
        closePopup.onclick = function() {
            overlay.style.display = 'none';
            popup.style.display = 'none';
        };
        // Show Overlay and Popup
        button.onclick = function() {
            overlay.style.display = 'block';
            popup.style.display = 'block';
        }
    </script>
```

http://polestarllp.com/polestarnew/category/blog/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are repeating IDs, it won't work. try using classes instead of IDs.

instead of

`document.getElementById("popupclose");`

use

`jQuery(".popupclose");`

Complete code.

HTML

```
<div class="griditemleft">
<div class="postimage">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"> <?php //the_post_thumbnail('category-thumbnail'); ?><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); } ?></a> <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
<div class="maincontent"> <button class="button">Readmore</button> </div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="popup">
   <div class="popupcontrols"> <span class="popupclose">X</span> </div>
   <div class="popupcontent"> <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="333" title="Front-contact-us"]');?> </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
jQuery(".button").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).closest('.overlay').show();
    jQuery(this).closest('.popup').show();
});


jQuery(".popupclose").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).closest('.overlay').hide();
    jQuery(this).closest('.popup').hide();
});
```

Comment: yes but , how can i do this . i am trying to remove id , then popup does not work

Comment: when i am trying to remove button id , or try to change id from class popup stop working

Comment: you should also update the code, I am updating the answer.

Comment: Do the same for other lines that are using getElementById method.

Comment: <div class="griditemleft">
<div class="postimage">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"> <?php //the_post_thumbnail('category-thumbnail'); ?><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
the_post_thumbnail(); } ?></a>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<div id="maincontent">
    <button id="button">Readmore</button>
</div><div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="popup"><div class="popupcontrols">
        <span id="popupclose">X</span>
    </div> <div class="popupcontent"> <?php  echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="333" title="Front-contact-us"]');?>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: these are php code wher i am trying to use  above popup script

Comment: you  there? looking forward for your answere

Comment: your code is ok , but it's not working , when i changes ever thing as a class but popup is not working

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("document").ready(function(){
jQuery(".button").click(function(){
    jQuery('.overlay').show();
    jQuery('.popup').show();
});
});


jQuery(".popupclose").click(function(){
    jQuery('.overlay').hide();
    jQuery('.popup').hide();
});